# The proof of inverse function theorem - two questions

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus

I have question about differentation in linear spaces. 
In proof of inverse function theorem I found remark about diferentation.
I underlined parts wich I am interested in.  [image]
[source](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~ralston/pub/ImplicitFT.pdf)
**Red one**
I get that

$\phi(x)= x +(f'(x_0))^{-1}(y-f(x)) = x + (f'(x_0))^{-1}(y) - (f'(x_0))^{-1}(f(x)) $

Hence : 
$\phi'(x) = I + 0 - ((f'(x_0))^{-1}(f(x)))'$
But what next, what to do with  $ ((f'(x_0))^{-1}(f(x)))' $ ?

It is my understeanding that $((f'(x_0))^{-1}(f(x)))'$ should be equal to $(f'(x_0))^{-1}f'(x)$ but why is that so? 

<s>**Green one**</s>

Is this green comes from definition of functions continuity? I mean if we take this definition :

[image]
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_function)

<s>Is $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$ here?</s>

**UPDATE** : Nevermind green one, it is from continuous differentiable function definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the expression $$\phi(x)= x +(f'(x_0))^{-1}(y-f(x)) = x + (f'(x_0))^{-1}(y) - (f'(x_0))^{-1}(f(x))$$ note that $(f'(x_0))$ is fixed. So, its derivative is zero. Thus,

$$((f'(x_0))^{-1}(f(x)))'= (f'(x_0))^{-1})'(f(x))+(f'(x_0))^{-1}(f(x))'$$

$$= 0(f(x))+(f'(x_0))^{-1}(f'(x))=(f'(x_0))^{-1}(f'(x)).$$

Comment: Would you be so kind to ellaborate why 'thus' is so obvious?

Comment: So this is function multiplication not composition ?

Comment: Both. If you have $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}^n$ given by $F(x)=Ax,$ where $A$ is a given matrix, then it is $F(G(x))=AG(x).$ Now, you can get the derivative of the composition as the derivative of the product. Note that $A$ is constant.